# Correlation analysis

Tags: r, regression, time-series, correlation, forecasting

I'm trying to measure the impact that rainfall causes in the number of incoming calls in a insurance-company. I have 4 years of daily data.

The plots below shown the correlation plot for each year:
[image]

The same plots as above, but now taken the weekly-mean for each variable:
[image]

The rainfall has a **yearly** seasonality and the call-center data has a **weekly pattern**. The idea is to come up with a *weekly-based model*, so that i can measure the impact that a *weekly mean rainfall forecast* will cause.

Plotting the whole dataset, taken weekly-means (image below):
[image]

I'd like some suggestions on how to measure this variable 'impact' - i can try to split the rainfall data into 3 categories (low, normal, high), then build some model.

Comment: Why do you regard these correlations as low?  If the insurance company deals with a range of circumstances, then the number of calls might be expected to relate to a number of variables of which rainfall would be just one, and it would be unlikely that the correlation between number of calls and any one explanatory variable would be > 0.5.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand that, what i mean by 'low correlation' is that a linear model won't solve my problem - model the 'impact' of rainfall. For example, one idea is to split the rainfall into 3 categories and then model each one separately - I just need to know in which direction/algorithm to look at.

Comment: I've added the time series tag, and you should check out all the (vast) time series literature because this looks a standard problem.  You will have to deal with the seasonality and the well known problem that correlations between non-stationary time series are often spurious (generally the solution is to transform or take differences or growth rates so the series become stationary).  On another point, just from the plots you've put up here I would have high hopes of building a model with rainfall as a continuous variable, I don't see why you would have to split it into three categories.

Comment: Thanks. I've done ARIMA models before, but in this case i don't need a pure forecasting model, instead what i need is to come up with some levels for the number of calls, and associate these levels with the rainfall.